# How create Schema from code with SailsJS & waterline

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

On SailsJS I know when we create models and change the migrate attribute,I start the server then Sails & waterline create the table.

But, It's possible to create table from JS ? without restart the server ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you cannot create schema without restart server
but you can install

```
npm install nodemon
```

then :

```
nodemon app.js
```

it will restart your server automatically